# Can we have a tag synonym to replace or have as an alternative to plot-explanation?

Tags: discussion, tags

What would you guys say if we shortened the tag ***plot-explanation*** to only ***p-e***?

It would come into handy and lots of people would probably use it.

**This is just a suggestion.**

Comment: If you find typing whole word hard, just type [tag:plot] or [tag:story] and they will redirect to [tag:plot-explanation].

Answer (score 5):

I don't see what this would accomplish. Tag synonyms are there to make it easier for users to discover tags by alternative (and maybe more intuitive to them) names. I can't for the life of me ever see anyone legitimately typing `p-e` and expect that to be a tag for plot explanations. How would anyone ever use that tag who is not aware of the synonymization?

If what you actually want is an easier way for people who *already know* about the tag to type it and not having to type the entire tag name, then try to type something like `plot`, or `pl` (or even just `p`) and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, tried that, it just says that the tag does't exist. That is why I asked it on this so then it could be created because that was the instructions for a tag synonym creation.

Comment: @natural As soon as you type `p`, the tag `plot-explanation` should pop up as the very first tag to choose from.